# 50% width inline child nodes wrap

Tags: css, html

I have two fieldsets (as below) that are inside a div. They have been style inline and 50% width. In my head I think they should display on the same line but (at least in chrome, haven't checked IE or ff) the second one wraps to the next line.

I have a twofold question:

1. Why oh why oh why!?
2. Is there an easy fix for this? (other than maybe setting them to be 49.8% width)?

http://jsfiddle.net/z22KR/2/

```
*
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
fieldset
{
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: grey;
}

div
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: green;
}

div div
{
    background-color: red;
}

<div>
    <fieldset>1</fieldset>
    <fieldset>2</fieldset>
    <div>div</div>
</div>
```

**Edit** I changed inline to inline-block as I intended. Sorry for the confusion there.

**Edit2** Also would rather not do any floating if at all possible.

**Edit3**
My html looks more like

```
<div class="twoChildren">
    <fieldset id="fieldset1"><legend>Fieldset 1</legend>
        <div id="listofStuff1">
            <table>
            ...
            </table>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="fieldset2"><legend>Fieldset 2</legend>
        <div id="listofStuff2">
            <table>
            ...
            </table>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure how to fix the problem you're having but one thing that jumped out at me straight away is you have your fieldsets display: inline, and then try to give them a width.  Inlined elements can't have a width.  Either try display: inline-block, or display: block; float: left; instead. Also, you might be better off using border: none; instead of border: 0px;

Comment: #GordonM Opps .. Well i've tried inline-block also in an earlier iteration, Must have left it in by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many mistakes in your css, please study and write logically. btw do you want like this??

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z22KR/6/)

#### EDIT

I find below things are not Good practice, please correct me if i am wrong

- Using `div div {}` is misleading, better use *class* and *id* selector
- also optimize your css , when you always need **margin ,padding and border to 0px**  then why dont you write on the top with ***{}**
- and also set the css in the order your elements are in the DOM, you first declare css for *fieldeset* then set css rule for *div*

@James Valid CSS is another issue and optimize CSS is another

Comment: Mistakes in my css? Its seems to be valid css3. I'd rather not have the Fieldsets float. It will break another part of my layout.

Comment: @diEcho Ah I think i understand what you mean now. I can't do a `*{margin/padding/border}` due to higher up's decisions. `div div{}` here was for the fiddle only - I don't actually have it in my markup.

Comment: @James, okay..thats why i mention..see my fiddle..please always exact what u have done on your side :)

Comment: @diEcho Lol!... exactly what i have is a html mess that is the size of my house. But you are right i should have specified. Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing there isn't any other way but to use float (or the nasty 49.8% trick). So best answer!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question why display: inline-block doesn't work.  The reason is because there was probably whitespace between the two divs.  This float solution is work around.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is caused by your HTML. All whitespace in HTML source code is displayed as a single space character - I'm not sure about the exact technical details of this. This space content between your div elements is what causes the second child div to wrap.

Changing the HTML code in your fiddle to the following solves your problem:

```html
<div><!--
    --><fieldset>1</fieldset><!--
    --><fieldset>2</fieldset><!--
    --><div>div</div><!--
--></div>
```

Or you could just write all tags adjacent to each other, as long as there's no whitespace between them.

Comment: You are correct. Unfortunately in my case I couldn't control the HTML a great deal. I ended up with the parent div `overflow: hidden` and the fieldsets `float: left; width: 50%; margin: 0;`

Comment: I see. Then I think you chose a reasonable solution. By the way, check out [this CSS-Tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) which covers a problem nearly equal to this one. Too bad most of the solutions don't apply to your situation though, but I thought it'd be nice to mention this.

Comment: Thats a great link. I think your answer would be even better if you took the flexbox example and put it in as a modern browser solution. I think this might actually work in my case and future users would probably find it useful.